# How to check if data exits before sending data in flutter provider

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make an application that saves user data in local storage that I am using a provider and I also have another provider that fetches profile data from API and this API requires user data I have stored in local storage now when I try to get profile data I want to make sure it exits how can I do that, here is my profile provider code:-

```
class ProfileProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  User? _user = null;
  bool isLoading = false;
  final _service = ProfileService();
  User? get profile => _user;

  Future<User> getProfile({required BuildContext context}) async {
    if (_user != null) {
      return _user!;
    }
    isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();

    final userData = context.read<AppService>().getUserAuthData();

    final res = await _service.get(userData: userData!);

    _user = res;
    isLoading = false;
    notifyListeners();

    return res;
  }

  void setProfile(User user) {
    _user = user;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void removerProfile() {
    _user = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: what's wrong with the code? Looks sound to me.

Comment: The problem is when i try get profile it can be null but i want to make sure i shouldn't be null

Comment: Okay, so if it's null fetch your details, assign to local and return the user or proceed with other fetching.

Comment: how can i do that

Comment: I can see in your code you only have fetching from server. Where's the local storage code? Or is that your question, how to store locally ?

Comment: no my question is how can i use this provider on my ui side

Comment: Use `Consumer` or `BlocBuilder` based on whether you using provider or bloc package.

Comment: If I understand your use case correctly, you could use `FutureBuilder`. In this case the `isLoading` variable is not needed.